# 2-Simplex.. filled or not filled?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology, simplex

I've seen some authors define the 2-simplex as the boundary of a triangle and others define it including the interior of the triangle (i.e. filling in the triangle). Does this distinction matter? Are they two different definitions?

Same question goes for the 3-simplex regarding the interior of the tetrahedron.

Thanks.

Comment: The simplex is filled. If you just take the boundary it is a different space.

Comment: Calling the 2-simplex the boundary of a triangle is *very* nonstandard. One ordinarily would refer to that as "the boundary of the 2-simplex".

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're talking about a geometric 2-simplex. Now, I can't tell whether you've encountered the following definition, but this is the one I was introduced to and it helps me picture a 2-simplex very clearly so I think it might help.

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{m}$ be a set of $n+1$ geometrically independent points. A geometrical n-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ is the following set: $$ \Delta(X) := \{Q = \sum\limits_{P \in X} a_{P}P \ | \ \sum\limits_{P \in X} a_{P} = 1, a_{P} \geq 0 \ \forall P \in X \} $$

Basically, this is the set of affine linear combinations of points in $X$ with the additional property that each coefficient $a_{P}$ is greater than zero.
If we choose $n=2$, this means that we are only considering the inside of the triangle whose vertices are the points in $X$ --and its border, of course --, instead of the whole affine 2-plane the vectors would span in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$.

If you allowed the coefficients to be negative, you could also obtain vectors in the affine 2-plane who point outside of the triangle.

Comment: Thanks, @AlexT. To clarify a couple things.. 1) for the 2-simplex would it then be right to think of the triangle living in 3-d space? I'm currently picturing the vertices on {x=1}, {y=1}, {z=1} and then the space in between is filled by your definition above. 2) What's the difference between the 'standard d-simplex' and the 'geometric d-simplex' (as you defined above)?